# rails 3.1 asset pipeline: *.css isn't precompiled, but it's in the manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**Setup**

- error.sass is under app/assets/stylesheets
- I ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
- error.css is in the manifest `error.css: error-8f9fb7a53be409476d28603c33a7cd1d.css`

**Problem**

`error.css isn't precompiled`

**Other odd things that may indicate problems with my setup**

- In [environment].rb `config.assets.compile = false`. This is desired. When I turn it to true it works, but I don't want live compile
- Everytime I load a page public/stylesheet gets generated with all the scss/sass files (but not css)
- This is an upgrade from rails 3.0, but I think the upgrade was succssful

Help?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default css and js files (except application.js and application.css) are not precompiled.  It looks like you can add `config.assets.precompile += %w( errors.css )` to fix your issue.  Also, there's more info about precompiling here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried restarting the server after you precompiled the assets?
The server will stick to the manifest.yml it had when you started the server.

(I know it's a late answer but I just had the problem :) )